# How to handle with null values in Scala case classes in Flink?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

Hello I'm reading JSON data from S3 with Flink, then I'm parsing the input to a case class. The problem is that when a JSON string has some null value the case class does not accept it cause each field of case class has a type (Int, String, etc).

Searching a solution I found that I can use Option to enable null values into a case class and it works, but the problem comes when I try to do a query after convert from Dataset to Table.

If I try to get the rows where score is null, I got nothing cause with Option Type represents an object.

```
//Case class that I used to parse a JSON
case class TestTableSchema(
    id: String,
    score: Option[Double]
)

val data: Dataset[TestTableSchema] = ...

tableEnv.registerDataSet("test_table", data)

val result = tableEnv.sqlQuery("""
    |SELECT *
    |FROM test_table
    |WHERE score IS NULL
    """.stripMargin
)
```

Also I checked that I can use a Row data type instead of a case class which accepts null values, but I didn't find some example to implement it.

How can I handle null values when I want to have a scheme?

Answer (score -1):

So what you could do is either:

1. Check for empty fields in your `.map` and transform it to something else like the string `"NULL"` or `"N/A"` if you still want to keep those in your result, or
2. Filter them out from your stream using `.filter`